# Plotting only selected rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, slice

I have a data frame called "df" with column = "date", "regions", "transactions". I want to plot the data frame in such a way so I can see transactions for only "selected regions" and not all the regions in my df.

For example- I want to see a plot with transactions for Regions = "a","X","z" only - all in the same graph - and "date" being my x-axis.
So far, I have been able to plot transactions data for all the regions in one graph but not able to slice my data for the regions that I want.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Please include an example of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

you can use df.loc to access only a group of rows or columns. Read below     https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

In your case, something like this would return the df with just the required regions

```
required_regions = ['a','X','z']    
df.loc[df['regions'].isin(required_regions)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply :) I will surely let you know if this works for me